# AppleScript in Distiller

Tags: applescript

I found a simple script to run Adobe Distiller on some file.

```
on run argv
    with timeout of (8 * 60) seconds
        tell application "Acrobat Distiller"
            Distill sourcePath item 1 of argv
        end tell
    end timeout
end run
```

How can I change page size inside this script?

Or should I modify `x.joboptions` file and ask Distiller to reload it?
How can I do it?

I'm new to AppleScript, and [the documentation for Distiller API](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=Distiller_AutomationIntro.60.1.html#1505885) is not enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is probably this:

```
Distill sourcePath in_file destinationPath out_file adobePDFSettingsPath opt_file
```

And the paths have to be absolute, not relative.